# How to change advance search url

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, advanced-search

How i can change advance search url /catalogsearch/advanced/ to /catalogsearch/result/ in **magento1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine these two because both are perform used for different search.

```
/catalogsearch/result/
```

is used for showing result when you search from input field in header.

```
/catalogsearch/advanced/result
```

is used for showing result when you advance search from in advance search page.

*Note: Both pages have different behavior can't combine unless you want same result on both.*

Comment: Yes you are right it will conflict, Thanks